# MessageEvent console.log is spamming my console can´t get rid of it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console, vite, console.log

[Message Event console.logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiDxI.png)
[MessageEvent info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g925g.png)
SO, as you guys can see in the img, im getting swated by this console.logs, and need help removing them, it says they come from a conten getdify.js

I know it is something i'm doing because they only appear when im working on a proyect or building something, in any other page this console.logs aren't there, im no expert but this thing is just annoying

1. Well i reaaally tried searching for people with the same issue but no luck, guess im the only bastard with this things
2. At the beginning tried to search for every possible lose console.log left alone no luck

Edit: Somethimes the console.log spamming just stop, I don't do anything different, just working suddenly stops.

Comment: Well thats a good chance for you to start learning what "debugger" is, how to get to the line that logs messages, how to put a breakpoint and how to read the callstack after breakpoint hit. And google has no idea about what "getdify.js" is and we cant see whats inside of it to check why it spams console logs. So we are unable to help you due to we dont have any "minimal reproducible example".

Comment: See https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/812

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For me, it is the cashback widget. Turning off the cashback widget was what stopped the massive spamming for me. Going into the Opera settings and then searching for "cashback" should be enough to find the setting.

[image: Opera cashback setting]

Comment: This should be accepted answer.

Comment: Indeed this solved everything

Comment: I had turned this off long ago however, I was also getting these messages.  The fix that finally worked for me was to turn it off in the opera flags: opera://flags.  See opera forum article https://forums.opera.com/topic/47377/addons-cashback-web-monitor/72

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED: it was a browser extension, to be more specific it was react-devtools, I'm using Opera but bc there is no react-devtools for Opera i just installed the Chrome one but yes, this extension was causing all this console.logs, now i just get one single console.log of a messageEvent

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Oh. That simple. Weird.

Comment: Indeed, I removed the React Dev Tools and it solved. Thanks!

Comment: It's not related to dev tools in any way. It's Opera's Dify cashback system which should be turned off. Opera is now bloated with tons of trash plugins causing various problems.

Answer (score 2):

You could also right click on the alerts and click on:

[image]

That way, the browser saves the filter for the next time:

[image]